# Same shape with different colors in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I am having following xml file.I want to make the shape of button circle with some background 
color.but my each button will contain different background color.For one button i can do it by taking 
        xml in drawable and define shape and color for button.but by this method i need to create
     separate xml file for each button for shape and color.but i want to do it in only one xml file which contain shape and different color so that i can reduce xml files in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                     />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                     />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                     />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not change the color or background Programmatically ?

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad yes this could be the one option for my problem but it will increase my code i am looking to minimize code as possible as i can

Comment: Then how could it be ?

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad can i do it one xml file

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad and if i cant then plz tell me how can i set the color and background of button programmatically

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad button should have circular in shape

Comment: you will make it circular in xml & will change the color in java code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad but when i tried to set shape from xml and change color programetically the shape of button again comes to it's default

Comment: where is the code of setting the shape ? I could not see any shape applied to your buttons in this xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795278/change-background-color-of-circular-button-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402012/how-to-set-rounded-buttons-with-background-color-and-change-color-on-pressed

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad i am just trying on demo code now so provided it.and the above mentioned problem occured in my project on which i am working

Answer (score 1):

Define shape  `roundbutton.xml` like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    </shape>
```

Then assign shape to your button

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/round1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

After that you can use java to change color

```
 round1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

And you need to `import android.graphics.Color;` not: `import android.R.color;`

Or  hex code (not 3-byte) `0xFF000000` where the first byte sets the alpha.